# Datatables: Export the table by breaking the column using delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatable, datatables

There are 2 columns in a row for my table. One is the key and other is the value.
The value can be single or multiple. If multiple, they are separated by `<br>`. Like:

`K1 -> V1 < br > V2 < br > V3`

Now I want to export this into an Excel file such that there will be a single row for each value. Like:

`K1 -> V1    \n K1 -> V2    \n K1 -> V3`

I want to do this using datatables but cannot find any success. Can anyone help plz.